# Why is my sitemap file tagged as "non-indexable"?

Tags: wordpress

We just recently discovered that our sitemap file's indexability is tagged as "non-indexable" during our audit. Here's how it looks like: https://prnt.sc/cgjNKVQviXOc. We're using WordPress with the latest version of the Avada theme. Any ideas please?